# How do you know how good or bad is a text with sentimental analysis using transformers?

Tags: python, pytorch, sentiment-analysis, huggingface-transformers

I am using the transformer sentimental analysis pipeline to get if a text is positive or negative like in the Huggingface webpage:

```
>>> results = classifier(["We are very happy to show you the  Transformers library.","We hope you don't hate it."])

>>> for result in results:
    print(f"label: {result['label']}, with score: {round(result['score'], 4)}")
```

And I get this as a result:

> label: POSITIVE, with score: 0.9998

One is the label and the other the probability of the label. What I want to get is the score of how good or bad is a text. For example, is not the same to say "you are good"  and "you are great", and either two are positive.

I saw that you can get labels between 1 and 5 but I also want to distinguish between those that are within the labels with a sentiment score between -1 and 1. At the end I want something like the following:

- "You are very good" - Label: 5 stars, score: 0.8
- "You are bad" - Label: 1 stars, score: -0.8
- "You are great" - Label: 5 stars, score: 0.9
- "You are good" - Label: 4 star, score: 0.65

Comment: You most likely have to retrain another model for star rating based off similar data because sentiment analysis is based off either positive or negative

Comment: Why do you want the sentiment score to be between -1 and 1? You could bin the current outputs into different categories. For example, 1 star for the range of values in 0 to 0.2, 2 stars for the values in 0.21-0.4 etc.

Comment: @yudhiesh at the end I want to do the same as the did in https://hedonometer.org/movies/Pulp%20Fiction/  but with transformers, so I need different scores. Having it between -1 and 1 was an example. The important fact is to have different scores